# Подключение телеграмм бота к битрикс24 через webhook

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, битрикс24, webhook

У меня возникла проблема. Мне нужно подключить телеграмм бота к битрикс24 через node js и webhook. Возможно ли это как-то сделать? И как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

на стороне Б24 создаёте исходящий вебхук для события указав url до скрипта.

- Разработчикам - Другое (готовые сценарии) - Исходящий вебхук

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при событии будет отправлен запрос на url, а дальше разбирайте и делайте что требуется.

пример на `Flask`, `Python`:

```
b24_url_user_get = 'https://example.bitrix24.ru/rest/user.get.json'

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def result():
    try:
        b24_token = requests.post(const.b24_oauth_token).json()['access_token']
    
        id_task = request.form['data[FIELDS_AFTER][ID]']  # получить id задачи из входящего запроса (событие)
        task = requests.post(const.b24_url_task_get, data={'taskId': id_task, 'auth': b24_token}).json()  # получить по id задачи данные задачи

        title = task['result']['TITLE']
        created = task['result']['CREATED_BY']
        responsible_id = task['result']['RESPONSIBLE_ID']
        responsible = task['result']['RESPONSIBLE_NAME'] + ' ' + task['result']['RESPONSIBLE_LAST_NAME']
        accomplice_quantity = task['result']['ACCOMPLICES']
```

Comment: Пытаюсь понять, что нужно писать в поле "URL вашего обработчика". Каким его делать?

Comment: в моём случае это https://IP:PORT/b24; а слушает nginx и перенаправляет в python скрипт

Comment: И  то есть потом оно приходит вам в чат битрикса?

Comment: Джуновский ум пытается понять. Просто я запустил ngrok на 8443 порту и вкинул после https://13946f17a833.ngrok.io токен приложения. И в консоли выводит 200 статус ОК, но когда я запускаю бота через "Контакт-центр">"Telegram", то оно не работает.

Comment: у меня настроен исходящий хук на событие Создание задачи и когда создаётся новая задача бот пишет ответственному по задаче (сопоставление айди юзера б24 и айди юзера телеграм) данные задачи и ссылку.

Comment: А я могу как-то с вами связаться?)

Comment: я не по node.js, а так пишите свой телеграм

Comment: @RIXIN101 вот он.